# How to get file upload progress in Apollo GraphQL client Android

Tags: android, okhttp, apollo-android

I've been looking ways to show upload progress in apollo graphql android library.
If anybody has done it please share the code.

Comment: Hi! You best bet in that case is most likely to look into OkHttp interceptors and overwrite the body with something that can track progress.

Comment: Need more info on what kind of client you are using for the file upload. This discussion may give you some direction: https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/issues/88